# How to extract specific columns from a space separated file in Python?

Tags: python, extract, pdb

I'm trying to process a file from the protein data bank which is separated by spaces (not \t). I have a .txt file and I want to extract specific rows and, from that rows, I want to extract only a few columns.

I need to do it in Python. I tried first with command line and used awk command with no problem, but I have no idea of how to do the same in Python.

Here is an extract of my file:

```
[...]
SEQRES   6 B   80  ALA LEU SER ILE LYS LYS ALA GLN THR PRO GLN GLN TRP          
SEQRES   7 B   80  LYS PRO                                                      
HELIX    1   1 THR A   68  SER A   81  1                                  14    
HELIX    2   2 CYS A   97  LEU A  110  1                                  14    
HELIX    3   3 ASN A  122  SER A  133  1                                  12    
[...]
```

For example, I'd like to take only the 'HELIX' rows and then the 4th, 6th, 7th and 9th columns. I started reading the file line by line with a for loop and then extracted those rows starting with 'HELIX'... and that's all.

EDIT: This is the code I have right now, but the print doesn't work properly, only prints the first line of each block (HELIX SHEET AND DBREF)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
 if 'HELIX' in line:
   helix = line.split()
 elif 'SHEET'in line:
   sheet = line.split()
 elif 'DBREF' in line:
   dbref = line.split()

print (helix), (sheet), (dbref)
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've currently got?

Comment: Post your code please. what specifically is your problem?

Comment: I have a total mess in my code, that's why I didn't post it... I don't even know what I am doing right now. My specific problem is that I need to find, with those rows starting by 'HELIX', specific columns. For those rows starting by 'SHEET' another specific columns, etc. So, I've done this after reading some comments:

for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
 if 'HELIX' in line:
  cols = line.split()
  print (cols[0], cols[3], cols[5], cols[6], cols[8])

the thing is: I'd like to don't have to do the same with those rows starting by 'SHEET' (changing only the position of cols that I want to extract).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have extracted the line, you can split it using `line.split()`. This will give you a list, of which you can extract all the elements you need:

```
>>> test='HELIX 2 2 CYS A 97'
>>> test.split()
['HELIX', '2', '2', 'CYS', 'A', '97']
>>> test.split()[3]
'CYS'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the CSV library.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
The following code should do the trick

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('my-file.txt', 'rb') as myfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(myfile, delimiter=' ', )
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print row[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't just use split?

```
for line in open('myfile'):
  if line.startswith('HELIX')
    cols = line.split(' ')
    process(cols[3], cols[5], cols[6], cols[8])
```

Comment: last column is supposed to be "97" and "122", but instead, last column returns "97" and "" because 122 is a three number digit and that changes the number of spaces between "A" and the final number and, in consequence, the number of columns...

Answer (score 0):

you can expend the key words as you want.
the result is list contained line with key words
you can do further process of result to get what you want

```
with open("your file") as f:
     keyWords = ['HELIX','SHEET','DBREF']
     result = [ line  for line in f for key in keyWords if key in line]
```