# Trouble reading data table from a URL into Python

Tags: python

I am relatively new to Python and I'm having problems reading in a data set and getting it in the form I need. The data set is an ASCII file of sea surface temperatures obtained from the NOAA site and has a format

```
YR MON NINO1+2 ANOM NINO3 ANOM NINO4 ANOM NINO34 ANOM
1982 1 24.29 -0.17 25.87 0.24 28.30 0.0026.72 0.15
```

I need to read the data in from the file stored on the NOAA site and then split the table into its separate columns. The following code seems to read in the table correctly, but I can't seem to separate the columns; the variables appear to be empty.

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/data/indices/sstoi.indices')
sst_data = response.read()

import StringIO
sst_data = StringIO.StringIO(sst_data)

import csv
r = csv.DictReader(sst_data)

for row in r:
    print row

year = []
month = []
for row in r:
    year.append(row['YR'])
    month.append(row['MON'])

print year
```

Comment: Your file is space separated not comma separated. You either need to read by line and split or set your delimiter to space. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768230/how-to-extract-specific-columns-from-a-space-separated-file-in-python

Answer (score 0):

If your CSV data isn't actually delimited by commas, you need to tell the reader what to split by like this:

```
r = csv.DictReader(sst_data, delimiter = " ", skipinitialspace = True)
```

Your data also seems to be delimited by different amounts of whitespace. skipinitialspace skips the prepending ones.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however that seems to makes matters worse in that all the columns seem to get confused and trying to extract the column of, e.g. years, or months, gives an empty variable. I've looked at the text file of the data itself, and there's nothing unusual in it, though it does seem that the header row has a variable number of spaces between columns, and the data themselves have 2 spaces.