# How to filter on fieldnames in first row of a text file in python

Tags: python, csv, filter, header

I've got the following text file:

```
id gen age mar loc inc iscr escr
51 F 46 M 0 15100 531 555
52 M 29 M 2 14200 673 633
53 M 25 S 0 22200 742 998
54 M 36 M 2 1000 677 646
55 F 99 S 0 10600 608 998
56 F 45 M 2 6100 710 743
57 M 99 M 2 16500 679 646
58 F 37 M 0 7400 637 683
59 M 45 S 0 22800 683 998
60 M 22 S 0 6400 699 998
61 M 32 S 0 3100 721 998
```

Now I want to make a function that filters on the fieldnames in the first row, so for example if you call the function: `filter('inc')` you get this list filtered on 'inc'. Anyone who can help?

Comment: You mean you get all `inc` from the file?

Comment: Use the library `pandas`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract specific columns from a space separated file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768230/how-to-extract-specific-columns-from-a-space-separated-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also create a function which gives you a list of dictionaries containing each of your rows in the text file data:

```
def get_data(filename):
    data = []

    with open(filename) as in_file:
        headers = next(in_file).split()

        for line in in_file:
            row = dict(zip(headers, line.strip().split()))
            data.append(row)

    return data
```

Which returns something along the lines of:

```
{'id': '51', 'gen': 'F', 'age': '46', 'mar': 'M', 'loc': '0', 'inc': '15100', 'iscr': '531', 'escr': '555'}
{'id': '52', 'gen': 'M', 'age': '29', 'mar': 'M', 'loc': '2', 'inc': '14200', 'iscr': '673', 'escr': '633'}
{'id': '53', 'gen': 'M', 'age': '25', 'mar': 'S', 'loc': '0', 'inc': '22200', 'iscr': '742', 'escr': '998'}
...
```

Then you can filter out this data using list comprehensions:

```
>>> data = get_data('filter.txt')
>>> [row['inc'] for row in data]
['15100', '14200', '22200', '1000', '10600', '6100', '16500', '7400', '22800', '6400', '3100']
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use `pandas` to manipulate data.

just

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
```

Then

```
df['inc'] # gets all inc values
df.iloc[0].inc # gets inc value for first row
```

Answer (score 1):

Import the `.txt` file as a csv using pandas, with a space `" "` as the delimiter, such as:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('your file.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
```

You can then select the columns you want using:

```
data['inc']
```

or

```
data['inc'].tolist()
```

if you want it as a list instead of a slice.

**Edit**

As pointed out in the comments, do not use `sep=" "` but rather `delim_whitespace=True`

Comment: For whitespace separators, `delim_whitespace=True`' is recommended